# Помогите создать еффект наложения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
.cs {
 padding: 50px 0 80px;
}
.cs h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 41px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.cs .t {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
 line-height: 23px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;

} 
.cs .t .wp:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.cs .t .wp {
 width: 75px;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.cs .t .wp img {
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 40px;
 position: relative;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
.cs .t .wp span {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs">
  <h2>24/7 Customer Support</h2>
  <div class="t">
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/22_qyfcaezY.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/26_UTZtK9MY.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/29_r2HPbRjc.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/47_K7bg36vA.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/56_WuDKKWiZ.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/79_Wq5Fue3t.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/59_MGrdWrHU.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/60_ZRwxcmfT.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/71_nvT8vFjV.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/79_Wq5Fue3t.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно реализовать эффект наложения так как указано на  картинке [image] 
И чтобы при hover картинка поднималься.Если кому надо вот [ресурс](https://www.tourradar.com/) где я нашел данный эффект. И если возможно чтобы при клике картинки справа и слева в котором был сделан клик отодвинулись так как показано на картинке . 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такая реализация:

```js
console.clear();
const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
const imgs = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

const sibs = (current) => {
 let prevSibling = current;
 let nextSibling = current;
 const next = [];
 const prev = [];
 
 while(nextSibling.nextElementSibling !== null) {
  nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
  next.push(nextSibling)
 };
 while(prevSibling.previousElementSibling !== null) {
  prevSibling = prevSibling.previousElementSibling;
  prev.push(prevSibling)
 };
 
 for(let item in next) {
  
  let num = (parseInt(item ) + 1)/next.length * 0.9;
  next[next.length - (parseInt(item) + 1)].style.opacity = num;
  
 }
 
 for(let item in prev) {
  let num = (parseInt(item) + 1)/prev.length*0.75;
  prev[prev.length - (parseInt(item) + 1)].style.opacity = num
 }
}
[...imgs].forEach(img => {
 document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  [...imgs].filter(item => {
   if(item !== img) {
    item.classList.remove('active');
    item.style.opacity = '1'
   }
  })
 })
 img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  sibs(img);
  
  [...imgs].filter(item => {
   if(item !== img) {
    item.classList.remove('active');
   } else {
    item.classList.add('active');
    item.style.opacity = '1'
   }
  })
 })
})
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
ul.hoverable li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-10%);
          transform: translatey(-10%);
}
ul li {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
          transform: translatez(0);
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 100px;
          flex: 0 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
ul li.active {
  margin: 0 10px 0 30px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
          transform: translatey(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="hoverable">
  <li><img src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/22_qyfcaezY.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/26_UTZtK9MY.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/29_r2HPbRjc.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/47_K7bg36vA.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/60_ZRwxcmfT.jpg" alt=""></li>
  
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: рочти угадали @NeedHate но после клика hover не работает у вас

Comment: за "почти угадал" отдельное спасибо. Изменил ответ, ховер оставил в прежнем состоянии.

Comment: Добавил отдельный клик по документу, который убирает все произошедшие события (т.н., дефолтное состояние).

Comment: спасибо ответ принял

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cs {
 padding: 50px 0 80px;
 background: #fff;
}
.cs h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 41px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.cs .t {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 48%;
 line-height: 23px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;

} 
.cs .t .wp:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.cs .t .wp {
 width: 75px;
 display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.cs .t .wp:active {
    margin: 0 40px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center
}
.cs .t .wp:active span {
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia,Nimbus Roman No9 L,serif;
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute
}
.cs .t a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px
}
.cs .t .wp img {
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 40px;
 position: relative;
 opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
.wp:hover {
    margin-bottom: 20px
}
.cs .t .wp span {
 display: none;
}
.cs .t:last-child {
 text-align: left;
}
.cs .t a {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs">
  <h2>24/7 Customer Support</h2>
  <div class="t">
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/22_qyfcaezY.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/26_UTZtK9MY.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/29_r2HPbRjc.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/47_K7bg36vA.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/56_WuDKKWiZ.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/79_Wq5Fue3t.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/59_MGrdWrHU.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/60_ZRwxcmfT.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/71_nvT8vFjV.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wp">
      <img class="lazy" src="https://cdn.tourradar.com/s3/team/original/79_Wq5Fue3t.jpg">
      <span>Brendan</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Просто надо было добавить псевдокласс `active`

```
.cs .t .wp:active {
    margin: 0 40px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center
}
.cs .t .wp:active span {
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia,Nimbus Roman No9 L,serif;
    width: 100%;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute
}
```

и все работает.Прошу рабочий пример смотреть только на польный екран.